# MoveBy Not Changing the Position of SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm using Sprite Kit to program a game. It is like the old game Snakey, where you start as one part of a snake but collect the apples and grow. To get the old fashioned movement, Im using SKAction MovyBy X: Y:. It is not changing the position of the node, but moving it.

I put an NSLog statement at the update section of the code getting the coords of the snake part. Every time it keeps returning the same cords, even though the snake part is moving.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the relevant code.

Comment: It would not just be helpful, it's a necessity.

Comment: You state that it is not changing the position of your node, but moving it.  Is movement in 2d not classified by changing position, whether from an SKAction or Physics Impulse/Velocity?

Comment: I actually figured it out, i wasn't referring to the node correctly so it wasn't changing the cords in the console. Thanks anyway, and thanks for the tip about posting the code.